# How to write a reads method of a trait

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a trait/case class setup like:

```
sealed trait Vehicle
case class Honda(...) extends Vehicle
case class Toyota(...) extends Vehicle

case class VehicleSet(bestSeller: Vehicle, others: Seq[Vehicle])
```

When I am writing the reads for VehicleSet it is saying

```
"No Json deserializer found for type Vehicle.  Try to implement an implicit reads or Format this type"
object VehicleJsonFormats {
  implicit val hondaWrites ...
  implicit val toyotaWrites ...
  implicit val vehicleSetWrites ...

  implicit val hondaReads ...
  implicit val tototaReads ...


  implicit val vehicleSetReads: Reads[VehicleSet] = (
    (JsPath \ "bestSeller").read[Vehicle] and
    (JsPath \ "other").read[Seq[Vehicle]]
  ) (VehicleSet.apply _)
}
```

I'm confused how this will work with a Trait?

Comment: Have you tried to write implicit reader inside Object VehicleSet?

Comment: @HendrikT implicit reader for what, the Vehicle trait?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a reader for your vehicle: `implicit val vehicleReads: Reads[Vehicle] = ???`. You will need some code to take your json and convert it to your vehicle instance: `Honda` or `Toyota`. This will depend on how you can differentiate your vehicles from the json objects.

Comment: @vdebergue but Vehicle is a trait.  I have implicit reads for both Honda and Toyota already.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Reads[Vehicle]` something like:

```
implicit val vehicleReads: Reads[Vehicle] = Reads[Vehicle] {
  case json: JsObject =>
    (json \ "make").asOpt[String] match {
      case Some("Honda") => hondaReads.reads(json)
      case Some("Toyota") => toyotaReads.reads(json)
      case _ => JsError("Vehicle expected")
    }
  case _ => JsError("JsObject expected")
}
```